# Need to add total to union query that already has count

Tags: php, mysql, count, sum, union

My problem has me stumped and I don't know where to educate myself on this challenge.

I have a bunch of kid's ages I'm counting up from data in a family event registration db built in php and mysql. The kids are registering themselves and declaring the tribe group and their age they belong to. There are multiple events scheduled for registration at any given time. At any time, the event hosts need to see the age counts.  The total count of kids in each column works in a mysql window but not in html.  The mysql results so far look like this:

```
custom  item_number1    Age 7   Age 8  ....
703198  Apache            1     NULL
703198  Arapahoe          2     5
703198  Aztec             1     NULL
703198  Blackfoot         1     5
703198  Cherokee          1     1
703198  Chippewa          1     1
703198  Creek             1     2
703198  Fox               1     1
703198  Iroquois          1     NULL
703198  Mohawk          NULL    4
703198  Pawnee            1     2
703198  Yellowknives      2     1
703198  All Tribes        13    22
```

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT 703198 AS custom, item_name1
     , COALESCE(item_number1,'All Tribes') AS item_number1
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 4 THEN 4 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 4'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 5 THEN 5 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 5'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 6 THEN 6 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 6'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 7 THEN 7 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 7'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 8 THEN 8 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 8'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 9 THEN 9 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 9'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 10 THEN 10 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 10'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 11 THEN 11 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 11'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 12 THEN 12 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 12'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 13 THEN 13 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 13'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 14 THEN 14 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 14'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 15 THEN 15 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 15'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 16 THEN 16 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 16'
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN Ages = 17 THEN 17 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Age 17'
   FROM ( SELECT item_number1
              , item_name1
              , item_name3 AS Item
              , item_number3 AS Ages
           FROM tbl_pp_transactions 
          WHERE custom = 703198 
            AND item_name3 = 'Daughter'
            AND item_number3 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT item_number1
              , item_name1
              , item_name4 AS Item
              , item_number4 AS Ages
           FROM tbl_pp_transactions 
          WHERE custom = 703198 
            AND item_name4 = 'Daughter'
            AND item_number4 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT item_number1
              , item_name1
              , item_name5 AS Item
              , item_number5 AS Ages
           FROM tbl_pp_transactions 
          WHERE custom = 703198 
            AND item_name5 = 'Daughter'
            AND item_number5 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT item_number1
              , item_name1
              , item_name6 AS Item
              , item_number6 AS Ages
           FROM tbl_pp_transactions 
          WHERE custom = 703198 
            AND item_name6 = 'Daughter'
            AND item_number6 IN (4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17)
       ) AS dt            
GROUP
    BY item_number1 WITH ROLLUP";
?>
```

I plan to shorten this up with a do/while loop once it works.  I'd like to get this into html using a prepared>statement approach.  But I don't think my binding names are correct.  Here's what I have:

```
<?php
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($query)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($custom, $item_name1, $item_number1, $Ages, $Item, $Item1, $Item3, $Item5, $Item7, $Item9, $Item11, $Item13, $Item15, $Item17, $Item19, $Item21, $Item23, $Item25);
?>
                    <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Tribe</th>
                            <th>Age 4</th>
                            <th>Age 5</th>
                            <th>Age 6</th>
                            <th>Age 7</th>
                            <th>Age 8</th>
                            <th>Age 9</th>
                            <th>Age 10</th>
                            <th>Age 11</th>
                            <th>Age 12</th>
                            <th>Age 13</th>
                            <th>Age 14</th>
                            <th>Age 15</th>
                            <th>Age 16</th>
                            <th>Age 17</th>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                                echo "<tr class='body_black'>";
                                printf("
                                <td><strong>%s</strong></td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                <td align='center'>%s</td>
                                ", $item_number1, $Ages, $Item, $Item1, $Item3, $Item5, $Item7, $Item9, $Item11, $Item13, $Item15, $Item17, $Item19, $Item21, $Item23, $Item25);
                                echo "</tr>";

                            }
                            $stmt->close();
                        }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

Any suggestions or direction would be great?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the final answer.  The labels needed to be changes from $Item to $Ages

```
$stmt->bind_result($custom, $item_name1, $item_number1, $Ages, $Ages1, $Ages3, $Ages5, $Ages7, $Ages9, $Ages10, $Ages13, $Ages15, $Ages17, $Ages19, $Ages21, $Ages23, $Ages25);

", $item_number1, $Ages, $Ages1, $Ages3, $Ages5, $Ages7, $Ages9, $Ages10, $Ages13, $Ages15, $Ages17, $Ages19, $Ages21, $Ages23, $Ages25);
```